# Running HP Load Runeer or QTP from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, qtp, loadrunner

I have HP Load Runner installed in Windows 2012 and its hosted in the cloud.

For running load runner scripts, I connect to the system via mstcs, open the `Virtual User Generator` application and run the scripts.

> Now I want to run the scripts via Jenkins( installed in a different system ) and I tried using the Jenkins HP Application Automation Tools plugin but I was unable to figure out how to do that.

In Jenkins I found out the following option:

- Execute HP functional tests from HP ALM
- Execute HP tests from file system
- Execute HP tests using HP ALM Lab Management
- Execute HP tests using HP Performance Center

But I am not sure how to use them or any of these will work. Can some please help me with this?

Comment: For those who are still looking for some detailed answer - http://www.testautomationguru.com/executing-qtpuft-scripts-using-jenkins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I figured out how to integrate it.

> **Integrating HP Load Runner:**

For Running HP Load Runner scrips there is a Jenkins plugin named **HP Application Automation Tools**.

The challenge for us was the fact that Jenkins and Load Runner were installed on separate machines. We had Jenkins installed in our Dev server and HP Load Runner installed on cloud. If both were installed on the same machine then the task would be as simple as providing the filesystem path for Load Runner Scenario *.lrs files, in Execute HP tests from file system plugin.

So I went ahead and installed a slave instance of Jenkins in our CTC in which Load Runner was installed.

> Steps to setup Jenkins slave instance.

1. On your master machine go to Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes.
2. New Node --> Enter Node Name.
3. Select Dumb Slave --> Press OK.
4. Fill out the following:

   - Set a number of executors (one or more) as needed.
   - Set a Remote FS Root, a home directory for the master on the slave machine. For a Windows slave, use something like: "C:\Jenkins\"
   - Set a label so that you can use that label to run jobs on the slave machine.
   - Select the appropriate Usage setting.
   - Launch Method: An easy way to control a Windows slave is by using Launch slave agents via Java Web Start  (Recommended for Windows).
     Availability --> Keep this slave online as much as possible
   - Press OK.

[image: Jenkins Slave configuration screenshot]

5. Now you need to connect your slave machine to the master using the following steps.

   - Open a browser on the slave machine and go to the Jenkins master server url (http: //your jenkins master:8080/).
   - Go to Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes, Click on the newly created slave machine. You will need to login as someone that has the "Connect" Slave permission if you have configured global security.
   - Click on the Launch button to launch agent from browser on slave.

[image]

- Run the program.

[image]

- Now you should see the Slave machine connected under Nodes.

[image]

6. If you want the service to run on start-up of the slave machine do the following (Windows only directions):

   - In the Slave agent program running on your slave machine, click File --> Install as Windows Service.
   - Start, type Services and Select the Services program.

[image]

- Find Jenkins Slave in the list, Double click to open.
- Select Startup type --> Automatic.
- Go to the Log On tab, change the Log on as to a user of your choice (Special user account Jenkins recommended).
- Make sure that auto login is set for the slave machine for the user account, then the VM (or physical computer) should connect and be available when needed.

> Creating Load Runner job in Jenkins:

1. Create a new freestyle project in Jenkins.
2. Check the "**Restrict where this project can be run**" checkbox and choose the **Label Expression** what you have provided for Slave Jenkins.
3. Under **Add build step** select **Execute HP tests from file system** and inside the **Tests** textarea provide the path of the folder of cloud machine which is having your Load Runner Scenario *.lrs scripts .
4. Click on build, Jenkins will trigger the Jenkins slave instance in cloud machine which will in turn invoke the Load Runner Controller and run the controller scripts(*.lrs).

> **Integrating HP QTP Scripts:**

Steps for integrating HP QTP Scripts are exactly same as for HP Load Runner, the only difference is :

1. HP Unified Functional Testing should be installed in the same machine where you are going to configure Jenkins as a slave instance.
2. Under Add build step select Execute HP tests from file system and inside the Tests textarea provide the path of the folder of CTC machine which is having your HP QTP scripts .

Answer (score 1):

For individual scripts alone, mdrv command line.   For controller alone wlrun command line.   You may refer to knowledge base articles on the arguments to employ.

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the documentation for [HP automation plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HP+Application+Automation+Tools)?

Answer (score 0):

Running Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter in a VM & want it set up as a jenkins node to run HP ALM test sets. In step 6, setting jenkins slave to run as a service, I received 'access denied' from jenkins slave agent process.  Open a cmd prompt as admin user, cd to the jenkins slave install directory and enter

jenkins-slave.exe install

to fix this. Next, run services, locate the jenkins slave service. Should say 'Automatic', so 'start' it up and trial run your jenkins job. Check by rebooting the new jenkins slave platform and checking the service comes back as 'Automatic'.